# Export pandas dataframe to a nested dictionary from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Its a similar question to

[Export pandas to dictionary by combining multiple row values](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32328/export-pandas-to-dictionary-by-combining-multiple-row-values?newreg=9a750025cabe46a98409beab476d6b0a[][1])

But in this case I want something different.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([
           ['A', 123, 1], 
           ['B', 345, 5], 
           ['C', 712, 4],
           ['B', 768, 2], 
           ['B', 768, 3], 
           ['A', 123, 9], 
           ['C', 178, 6], 
           ['C', 178, 5],  
           ['A', 321, 3]], 
           columns=['maingroup', 'subgroup', 'selectedCol'])
```

I'd want the output to be:

```
{
 'A': {'123':[1, 9], '321':[3]},
 'B': {'345':[5], '768':[2, 3]},
 'C': {'712':[4], '178':[6, 5]}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using dict comprehension with nested groupby:

```
d = {k: f.groupby('subgroup')['selectedCol'].apply(list).to_dict()
     for k, f in df.groupby('maingroup')}
```

Output:

```
{'A': {123: [1, 9], 321: [3]},
 'B': {345: [5], 768: [2, 3]},
 'C': {178: [6, 5], 712: [4]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit complicated, but maybe someone has a better solution. In the meantime here we go:

```
df = df.groupby(['subgroup']).agg({'selectedCol': list, 'maingroup': 'first'})
df = df.groupby(['maingroup']).agg(dict)
df.to_json(orient='columns')
```

I did in two steps:

- first merging the selectedCol to get a list:

[image]

- then create the 2nd level dictionary

[image]

- extract to json

[image]

There might be a cleverer way to do this by playing around with the orient parameter in the to_json method.

Edit: which part of the code fails? 1, 2 or 3?
My notebook screenshot. check your version:

[image]

or maybe try this:

```
df.groupby(['subgroup']).agg({'selectedCol': list, 'maingroup': 'first'}).groupby(['maingroup']).agg(dict)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... I get a `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

Comment: Added my reply to the original answer as an edit. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I received a simpler answer from stackoverflow. I'll post it here for completion. Thank you @RonsenbergVI